# Why Does my Palindrome Code not work? My reverse variable does what it is supposed to but I dont get true even when it is printing out a palindrome

Tags: java, c#, boolean, palindrome

```
public class NumberPalindrome {
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
        int reverse = 0;
        if (number<0){
            number=number* -1;
        }
        while (number > 0) {
            int lastDig = number % 10;
            reverse = lastDig + reverse;
            if (number<10) {break;}
            reverse = reverse * 10 ;
            number/=10;
        }
        if (number==reverse) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 
}
```

why does my code not return true when I enter a palindrome number? I tried using it to print out the reverse value and it does it quite well, but just does not seem to get the boolean value straight though.

Comment: Can you first tell us what language this is supposed to be written in?  Tagging both java and c# is not helpful.

Comment: `return number.ToString().SequenceEqual(number.ToString().Reverse())` would do, by the way

Answer (score 2):

The problem was modifying the number variable, but then comparing it with the new generated reverse variable as if it was never edited.

Also, you were adding the last digit to the reverse variable before multiplying it by ten.

See the following code in Java:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    int reverse = 0;

    if(number < 0) {
        number *= -1;
    }

    int initialNumber = number;

    while(number > 0) {
        int lastDigit = number % 10;

        reverse = (reverse * 10) + lastDigit;

        if(number < 10) {
            break;
        }

        number /= 10;
    }

    return initialNumber == reverse;
}
```

Comment: 1) `reverse * 10` does not need parentheses because multiplication `*` has higher priority than addition `+` 2) copied `if (number < 10) {break; }` seems to be redundant - `while` loop ends without this `if` anyway.

Comment: You can remove the test number < 10: number will be divided by 10, giving 0, and the loop exits.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here. You need to save the original number for comparison with the the reversed number. The break statement confuses the logic.

To figure this out, I added some print statements to trace the progress. Adding print statements isn't elegant, but it is very useful.

Here is my version, with comments indicating what I changed.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome (int original)
{
    // Need to save the original number for comparison
    int number = original;
    int reverse = 0;
    if (number < 0)
    {
        number = number * -1;
    }
    while (number > 0)
    {
        int lastDig = number % 10;
        // Update and shift reverse in one step
        reverse = lastDig + reverse * 10;
        number /= 10;
        // Don't need extra break to terminate the loop
        System.out.printf ("Check %d ; Reverse %d%n", number, reverse);
    }
    System.out.printf ("Final %d ; Reverse %d%n", number, reverse);

    // Compare to original and return boolean value directly
    return (original == reverse);
}
```